# Move first array element one row down

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to implement the same python code for the following r code:

```
nm <- c("Sepal.Length" ,"Sepal.Width" , "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species")
nm_data <-
  sapply(1:length(nm), function(i)
    c(nm[-(0:i)], nm[0:i])) %>% data.frame()
comb_predictors <- list()
for (i in 1:length(nm_data)) {
  comb_predictors[[i]] <- nm_data[1:i, ]
}
```

It should move the first element in the list one row down, and for each column until the last column when it returns to the beginning.

As for `nm_data`, I have tried the following python attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
nm = ["Sepal.Length" ,"Sepal.Width" , "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"]


def tbl(data, x):
    df=np.transpose((data[::-x], data[0:x]))
    return(pd.DataFrame(df))
cnt = [x for x in range(0, len(nm))]
list(map(tbl, nm, cnt))
```

However, I get the following result:

```
[  0
 0  
 1  ,
    0
 0  S
 1  S,
     0
 0  Pe
 1  Pe,
      0
 0  Pet
 1  Pet,
       0
 0  Spec
 1  Spec]
```

If I do

```
tbl(nm, 1)


0   1
0   Species Sepal.Length
1   Petal.Width Sepal.Width
2   Petal.Length    Petal.Length
3   Sepal.Width Petal.Width
4   Sepal.Length    Species
```

however, I cannot get it like the expected output. I know that for `comb_predictors` I just run it in a for loop so thats easy enough to get. But I am having trouble with getting `nm_data` with python.

My expected result:

```
1  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species Sepal.Length
2 Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width
3  Petal.Width      Species Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length
4      Species Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width
5 Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species
```

Comment: `arr = np.array(nm)[[1,2,3,4,0]]; r = np.arange(len(arr)); pd.DataFrame(arr[(r + r[:,None]) % len(arr)].T)`, IIUC. I don't understand why *nm* isn't in the desired order or what the included python implementation is intended to achieve.

Comment: Or `pd.DataFrame(scipy.linalg.circulant(nm)[:,::-1])`

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny the scipy trick is really neat! They have a few very handy functions that will come in handy in future for myself. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overcomplicated it - you need only

```
data = [nm[x:] + nm[:x] for x in range(1, len(nm)+1)]
```

And eventually later you can convert it to `DataFrame`

---

Minimal working code

```
import pandas as pd

nm = ["Sepal.Length" ,"Sepal.Width" , "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"]

data = [nm[x:] + nm[:x] for x in range(1, len(nm)+1)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
              0             1             2             3             4
0   Sepal.Width  Petal.Length   Petal.Width       Species  Sepal.Length
1  Petal.Length   Petal.Width       Species  Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width
2   Petal.Width       Species  Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width  Petal.Length
3       Species  Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width  Petal.Length   Petal.Width
4  Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width  Petal.Length   Petal.Width       Species
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also use `collections.deque()` to rotate list:

```
import pandas as pd
import collections

nm = ["Sepal.Length" ,"Sepal.Width" , "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"]

data = []

d = collections.deque(nm)

for _ in range(len(nm)):
    d.rotate(-1)
    data.append(list(d))
    #print(list(d))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

Comment: I added example with `collections.deque`